# Developing Webapp with PHP and Postgre in Windows is the same than doing it in Linux?

Tags: php, linux, windows, postgresql, ubuntu

I have to develop a webapp for the company in which I am doing my internship.

They asked me to develop it using PHP and PostgreSQL. (That is just how they do things, I usually use mysql)

Most computers there have Ubuntu.
Call me crazy but I like developing websites in Windows...

So, if I develop the website in Windows using PHP and PostgreSQL, will it run with no problems in Ubuntu?

I just have to worry that it is supported in most browsers right?

Your responses, tips, and help will be very appreciated.

Comment: i develop on a windows machine, but the files get automatic then transferred to the work *nix box; best of both worlds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, if I develop the website in Windows using PHP and PostgreSQL, will it run with no problems in Ubuntu?

*Maybe*.

> I just have to worry that it is supported in most browsers right?

*Probably*.

Tip: Virtualize an Ubuntu box on your Windows computer then the development environment is the same as the production environment. This is what you normally aim for. If the application is trivial, this is normally not necessary, but as you use a different database server it's probably already the way to go. keep in mind that many things work better under linux then windows in the PHP world, especially the extension situation is much better.

Comment: thanks! I feel kind of obligated to do it in ubuntu now

Answer (score 1):

Some things might work diffrent. Just develop it on your windows machine and test it on a ubuntu machine / VM.

If you get any errors you were not having on windows there's probably a solution on php.net (also read the comments)

Also make sure every machine the app is hosted on is haves the same (major) php version.

I also develop on windows. The way I do is everything I work on gets saved to a network share on a debian linux machine. Then I point my browser to the webserver on the debian linux box so it gets tested in a linux envoirment. Instead of an samba share you can either use a ftp or sftpserver. Most IDE's support uploading to (s)ftp